# How can I able to render a .gif file into jpeg mobile frame to my Gatsby site

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, gatsby

I want to render .gif file to a mobile.png to my gatsby site but not able identify a proper resource for it.
could any have an idea how's that possible to render a .gif file to .png mobile frame for Gatsby site

Here's the frame
[image]

Comment: option 1: use a video editor to get the gif framed
or
option 2: use parent component with `position: relative;` and `position absolute;` on the child components with the frame on higher z-index

Comment: how to render gif in gatsby?

Comment: pretty sure you can use img tags for gifs too

Answer (score 1):

You have a [Working with GIFs guide](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/images-and-media/working-with-gifs/). You just need to import the `.gif` asset as any other asset to allow webpack to get the source of that file and display it in a `<img>` tag:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import Layout from '../components/layout'
import otterGIF from '../gifs/otter.gif'
const AboutPage = () => (
    return (
        <Layout>
            <div class="yourLayout">
              <img src={otterGIF} alt="Otter dancing with a fish" />
            </div>
        </Layout>
    )
)
export default AboutPage;
```

The key part is to set the mobile frame as a background of the `yourLayout` `div` so it can wrap the GIF inside:

```
.yourLayout {
   position: relative;
   background: url('../path/to/asset.png') no-repeat center center / 100% 100%;
   width: 500px; //define a constraints if necessary 
   height: 800px;  //define a constraints if necessary 
}

.yourLayout img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain; // work with this property to adjust it if needed
}
```

Basically, you are setting `yourLayout` `div` as a frame while the image inside (the GIF) will take all the available space because of the position absolute.

There's a lack of details in your question so, depending on your structure, you may not need to use the constraints.